# Elegant way to do associated "data items"

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

I am trying to have associated "data items" of `ContentType` of and its content:

```hs
data ContentType = MyInt | MyBool deriving ( Show )

data Encoding'
  = EncodingInt  [Int]
  | EncodingBool [Bool]

chooseContentType :: IO ContentType
chooseContentType = undefined
```

How do I make something like this, but type-checked?

```hs
data Encoding a =
  Encoding { contentType :: ContentType
           , content :: [a]
           }
```

Comment: probably something with GADTs and `MyInt :: ContentType Int | MyBool :: ContentType Bool`

Comment: `Encoding'` looks very idiomatic to me. What don't you like about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The feature you're looking for is called [generalized algebraic data types](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GADT) (or GADTs, for short). It's a GHC extension, so you'll have to put a pragma at the top of your file to use them. (I'm also including `StandaloneDeriving`, because we'll use that to get your `Show` instance in a minute)

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, StandaloneDeriving #-}
```

Now you can define your `ContentType` type fully. The idea is that `ContentType` is parameterized by the (eventual) type of its argument, so `ContentType` will have kind `* -> *` (i.e. it will take a type argument).

Now we're going to write it with a bit of a funny syntax.

```
data ContentType a where
  MyInt :: ContentType Int
  MyBool :: ContentType Bool
```

This says that `MyInt` isn't just a `ContentType`; it's a `ContentType Int`. We're keeping the type information alive in `ContentType` itself.

Now `Encoding` can be written basically the way you have it.

```
data Encoding a =
  Encoding { contentType :: ContentType a
           , content :: [a]
           }
```

`Encoding` also takes a type parameter `a`. Its content must be a list of `a`, and its content type *must* be a content type that supports the type `a`. Since our example has only defined two content types, that means it must be `MyInt` for integers or `MyBool` for Booleans, and no other encoding will be supported.

We can recover your `deriving (Show)` on `ContentType` with a `StandaloneDeriving` clause (this is the second GHC extension we turned on in the above pragma)

```
deriving instance Show (ContentType a)
```

This is equivalent to your `deriving` clause, except that it sits on its own line since the GADT syntax doesn't really have a good place to put one in the same line.

Comment: If I use GADTs, is it possible to write a function with type `chooseContentType :: IO (ContentType a)`? If the IO input decides if we want `MyInt` or `MyBool`.

Comment: @gust You can use [existential quantifiers](https://wiki.haskell.org/Existential_type) to hide the extra type parameter again. But the resulting type won't be of much good to you. If you don't know the type of `a` at compile-time, there's no good way to construct an `a` hence to construct an `Encoding a`. If you have a more concrete example of how you want to use the result of `chooseContentType`, I can try to be more specific, but as far as I can see, that function (even if you write it with existentials) won't be too useful